# How to install Photoshop CC 2018 on Fedora 27?

Tags: windows, fedora, adobe-photoshop

I have Photoshop CC 2018 on a Windows machine but I need to transfer it to a machine that has Linux. Is it possible to transfer the files and run the program from the Linux?

I've read about running Photoshop by using an emulator called Wine but is there any difference with the Photoshop that runs on windows?

Comment: Yes, for one you need to run the emulator. Sorry but it's unclear what your requirements are or why you're trying to do this. If you look at the [official requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/system-requirements.html) you will find there is no official Linux support.

Comment: Wine isn’t an emulator

Comment: If you get Photoshop working with Wine, there will be nearly no differences, but not every program works with Wine.  If you need to run Photoshop then run a Windows VM or Windows itself

Comment: I ran a Windows in a virtual box on my Linux and then I ran Photoshop inside the virtual box and it is working fine but it is very slow. I need the latest version of Photoshop running on my Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely recommend against attempting to run Photoshop CC 2018 using Wine.

According to the website that tracks Wine software compatibility, [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=36206), Photoshop 2018 CC *can* run on Linux using Wine, but it will not run perfectly.  There wasnt extensive testing, only three different Linux distros are listed as being tested, and no Fedora version was listed as one of them.  There were issues listed, with possible workarounds.

Assuming everything works on your Linux distro (and that is a **BIG** if), there would be no difference running on Linux.  It would look and behave just like running on Windows. 
 However, running any program on Wine, your mileage my vary.  If you can avoid running Photoshop using Wine, I would recommend it.  While Wine does allow some Windows programs to run in Linux, there are just to many issues.  The more complex the program is, the more problems occur.

If you want to try, again I recommend against it, there are a number of tutorials on how to [install Wine](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20wine%20tutorial&oq=linux%20wine%20tu&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0.6977j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), as well as install Windows software using Wine.  In general this is an easy process, but there are always caveats and pitfalls that will come up.

Instead of running Photoshop in Wine, I would *highly* recommend another solution. 
 As an alternative to Photoshop on Linux, I would recommend [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/).  Gimp will run natively on Linux (and Windows) and has most of the same features as Photoshop.  Another alternative would be [Gimpshop](https://www.gimpshop.com/).  Gimpshop is an offshoot of Gimp that replicates the feel of Adobe Photoshop. Its primary purpose was to make users of Photoshop feel comfortable using GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can transfer all your PSD files (files) and config files over to your WINE based version.

The file you want to copy for settings is Prefs.psp
Should be located in `Documents and Settings/[user name]/Application Data/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop [version]/Adobe Photoshop [version] Settings`

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/preference-file-names-locations-photoshop.html

To install Photoshop itself on Linux, I have personally tried to use WINE which worked for CS5 and CS6. Then PlayOnLinux worked for CC 2016.

Since Photoshop CC 2018, I have used Crossover to install Photoshop CC 2018.

It works on all Linux versions, you can Crossover from their website https://www.codeweavers.com/

Here is a guide to installing it on Arch https://sick.codes/arch-linux-photoshop-cc-2018-2019-working/

GIMP is a good alternative, but it doesn't have any of the content-aware tools, the stamp repair tools. Adobe Photoshop has incredible, but proprietary, algorithms for these tools.

Use Crossover to install it natively on Fedora.